# Removing null value from the JSON

Tags: javascript

I have below JSON. how to remove the property from the object which contain blank (""), null, undefined value using Javascript?

```
dataJSON==
    {
      "Cli Info:Sub_Ind":""
      "Cli Info:Sub_Mat":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_Ewwu":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_kjlo":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_uti":"",
      "S Funds:S_C_origin":"Afghanistan;Albania",
      "S We:Count_we":"Antigua & Barbuda;American Samoa;Austria",
      "Add Juri:Jurid_Coun":"Andorra;Angola"
     }
```

i tried the approach but not working.

```
 function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

I am expecting to remove all the null,blank and undefined values from the JSON

Comment: Are you interested in Javascript or Java? They're completely separate languages.

Comment: An empty string is still a string and therefor not a null or undefined

Comment: Be careful about referring to an objec as  "a JSON".  JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation"

Comment: Just add  `obj[propName] === ""` in if statement. String empty not a null or undefined

Comment: There is no JSON shown here. JSON is a way of representing data *as a string of text* to transmit between systems, save to a file, etc. It is *based on, but not the same as* the syntax used in JavaScript to create an object. What you have there is *a simple JavaScript object*, it is not a string. Misunderstanding this difference will cause you all sorts of confusion when you do encounter some actual JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fastest way could be to use `Set` (on big objects):

```js
const obj =
    {
      "Cli Info:Sub_Ind":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_Mat":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_Ewwu":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_kjlo":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_uti":"",
      "S Funds:S_C_origin":"Afghanistan;Albania",
      "S We:Count_we":"Antigua & Barbuda;American Samoa;Austria",
      "Add Juri:Jurid_Coun":"Andorra;Angola"
     };
     
const set = new Set([null, undefined, '']);
for(const key in obj){
  set.has(obj[key]) && delete obj[key];
}

console.log(obj);
```

There's an interesting thing. If we compare the value against undefined, null and '' the order is important, So if we don't know which data we have (what it will contain the most for example null or ''), the `Set` is faster and handles any data equally:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">
const chunk = Object.entries({
  "Cli Info:Sub_Ind": "",
  "Cli Info:Sub_Mat": "",
  "Cli Info:Sub_Ewwu": "",
  "Cli Info:Sub_kjlo": "",
  "Cli Info:Sub_uti": "",
  "S Funds:S_C_origin": "Afghanistan;Albania",
  "S We:Count_we": "Antigua & Barbuda;American Samoa;Austria",
  "Add Juri:Jurid_Coun": "Andorra;Angola",
  "Boolean": false,
  "Number": 0
});

const obj = {};
let i = 100000;
while(i--){
  Object.assign(obj, Object.fromEntries(chunk.map(([key,val])=>([key+i, val]))));
}

// @benchmark if
for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === "") {
    delete obj[key];
  }
}
obj;

// @benchmark set
const set = new Set([undefined, null, '']);
// @run
for (const key in obj) {
  set.has(obj[key]) && delete obj[key];
}
obj;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Group in an array all the values you want to remove, then use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method and [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) all the object elements that satisfy the condition.

```js
for (const key in dataJSON) 
  if (["", null, undefined].includes(dataJSON[key]))
    delete dataJSON[key];
```

A little demo:

```js
const foo = {
  a: "",
  b: "Bar",
  c: null,
  d: "Bin",
  e: undefined,
  f: "Baz"
};

console.log("Before cleaning:", foo);

for (const key in foo)
  if (["", null, undefined].includes(foo[key]))
    delete foo[key];

console.log("After cleaning:", foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using You can do it in this way using Object.entries() to convert the JSON object into an array and `Array.prototype.filter()`, it filters out the entries where the value is ("") blank, null, or undefined

```js
const dataJSON = {
  "Cli Info:Sub_Ind": undefined,
  "Cli Info:Sub_Mat": null,
  "Cli Info:Sub_Ewwu": "",
  "Cli Info:Sub_kjlo": "",
  "Cli Info:Sub_uti": "",
  "S Funds:S_C_origin": "Afghanistan;Albania",
  "S We:Count_we": "Antigua & Barbuda;American Samoa;Austria",
  "Add Juri:Jurid_Coun": "Andorra;Angola",
  "Boolean": false,
  "Number": 0
};

for (const key in dataJSON) {
  if (dataJSON[key] === "" || dataJSON[key] === null || dataJSON[key] === undefined) {
    delete dataJSON[key];
  }
}

console.log(dataJSON);
```

Comment: the op needs delete in place

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev What do you mean by op needs delete in place?You've mentioned "I am expecting to remove all the null,blank and undefined values from the JSON"

Comment: the intent of the OP seems to clear the existing JS object, not getting a cleared copy

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev modify the question as remove the property from the object. Updated the code as per your ask

Comment: that deletes false and 0 which is bad

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev check for all the condition which you want to delete. Added false and 0 in the object for reference

Comment: looks fine now!

Answer (score -1):

This removes null and undefined values with a for in loop (**PURE Javascript**):

```
dataJSON==
    {
      "Cli Info:Sub_Ind":""
      "Cli Info:Sub_Mat":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_Ewwu":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_kjlo":"",
      "Cli Info:Sub_uti":"",
      "S Funds:S_C_origin":"Afghanistan;Albania",
      "S We:Count_we":"Antigua & Barbuda;American Samoa;Austria",
      "Add Juri:Jurid_Coun":"Andorra;Angola"
     }

for (const key in dataJSON) {
  if (dataJSON[key] == null) {
    delete dataJSON[key];
  }
}
```

**Note:** Feel free to add the empty string on the if statement.

Comment: the code got worse from the op's question, not a complete answer

Answer (score -1):

Use your code, have an empty object literal, and use `Object.assign` inside the loop as an option. Change your condition to check not-nullish values.

Comment: the op needs to delete in place